# Restart app on PACKAGE_REPLACED not working

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want my app to restart automatically after update.
Following is my manifest and broadcast receiver code:

```
...
    <receiver
        android:name="app.com.blynq.services.BootReceiver"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" android:path="app.com.blynq.player" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
...
```

Service:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String intentActionString = intent.getAction();
    if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intentActionString) || "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED".equals(intentActionString)) {
        Intent pushIntent = new Intent(context, RegisterActivity.class);
        pushIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(pushIntent);
    }
}
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Those `intent-filter` tags need to be inside a `receiver` tag.  Are they?  If so, please include it in the post.

Comment: Is `app.com.blynq.services.BootReceiver` the correct Java class name?  Just a hunch, but it sounds like you mistakenly added "app", which is the default module name, not part of the class name.

Comment: And I don't think [`android:permission`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html#prmsn) does what you think it does here.

Comment: Yes, that is the correct class name. Is it not in accordance with common practices? Also, is android:permission - not required here ?

Comment: So your `BootReceiver` class is in Java package `app.com.blynq.services`?  Conventionally, the package name would begin with `com`.  But that isn't the problem if the package name is correct in the manifest.

Comment: If you have an Asus device or use app like greenify pay attention to manager apps [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44415369/6548766)